# How do I run a count of rows over a database link?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

This code, works. It runs a row count the way you'd expect, I want to tweek it, mostly to do a count over a db_link for tables dictated as I see fit.

```
declare
n number;
begin
for i in (select table_name from user_tables) loop
execute immediate' select count(*) from '||i.table_name into n;
dbms_output.put_line('Table Name: '||i.table_name||' Count of Row''s: '||n);
end loop;
end;
/
```

So, this is the adapted code... it includes a variable with the name of the link. (The link works fine) But how to reference it is probably where I'm coming unstuck.

```
declare
l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';
n number;
begin
for i in (select table_name from my_tables) loop
execute immediate' select count(*) from '||i.table_name@||l_dblink into n;
dbms_output.put_line('Table Name: '||i.table_name||' Count of Row''s: '||n);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Can someone please have a look and tell me where I'm going wrong? I just want the SQL to pick up the table names from a local table, and then use the names to count the rows in those tables, which reside in the remote database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Monkey* is on the wrong *tree* and can't eat a banana.

```
SQL> create table my_tables (table_name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_tables values ('dual');

1 row created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'db1';
  3    n number;
  4  begin
  5    for i in (select table_name from my_tables)          --  has to be like this
  6    loop                                                 --      vvv
  7      execute immediate' select count(*) from '||i.table_name || '@' || l_dblink into n;
  8      dbms_output.put_line('Table Name: '||i.table_name||' Count of Row''s: '||n);
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /
Table Name: dual Count of Row's: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```